# jQuery Parent for specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have php structure as following:

```
<div class="top"> 
 <div class="middle">
    <?php echo '<a class="delete" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ?>
         <div class="delete_button">Delete</div>
    </a>
 </div>
</div>

<!--Different post -->
<div class="top"> 
 <div class="middle">
    <?php echo '<a class="delete" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ?>
         <div class="delete_button">Delete</div>
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then here is js.

```
jQuery('.delete').live('click',function(){
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");
    var post  = jQuery(this).parent();   //????????
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : custom.ajax_url, 
        data : { 'action':'deletePost' , post_id:post_id},
        success : function(data){                       
            post.fadeOut();
        }
    });                 
 });
```

So, as you can see I have two div containers that have different `post_id`.

With the js, I want to target the specific "`top`" div to be fadeout.

Do I have the `var post  = jQuery(this).parent();` right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
jQuery(this).parents('.top');
```

or

```
jQuery(this).closest('.top');
```